# Flutter - How can I use firebase remote config as a stream?

Tags: flutter, firebase-remote-config

How can I use firebase remote config as a stream? In Flutter. What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the StreamBuilder widget

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.getValue("something").asStream(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<RemoteConfigValue> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return SomeWidget(....
```

Comment: such a thing is impossible

Answer (score 0):

You could use with `onConfigUpdated.listen()`.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
  
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    var example = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.getString("EXAMPLE");
    final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
    late StreamSubscription<RemoteConfigUpdate> _streamSubscription;

    @override
    void initState() {
      firebaseRemoteConfig();
      super.initState();
    }
  
    @override
    void dispose() {
      _streamSubscription.cancel();
      super.dispose();
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
    }
  
    void firebaseRemoteConfig() {
      _streamSubscription = remoteConfig.onConfigUpdated.listen((event) async {
        await FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.activate();
  
        if (event.updatedKeys.contains("EXAMPLE")) {

          var example_ = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.getString("EXAMPLE");
  
          setState(() {
            example = example_;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  
  }
```

And you could start the fetch process in `main()`

```
await FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.fetchAndActivate();
```

With `this(onConfigUpdated.listen())` you will lower the throttling risk. If you want just use remote config in one page, don't forget to cancel the streamsubscription in dispose or it will cause memory leak.

Check this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP9Kb5AxkiU